# Issue centering a div between two floats

Tags: css, css-float, center

I found a solution on this site to **[center a div between two floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172738/centering-a-div-between-one-thats-floated-right-and-one-thats-floated-left)** . The solution works fine except that I have a double border now.

**CSS**

```
.trilink_container {
margin:5px;
overflow: hidden; /* contain floated elements */
}

.trilink_all {
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
color: #444444;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #F6F6F6;
background: #fdfdfd;
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fdfdfd,  #eee);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fdfdfd,  #eee);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fdfdfd,  #eee);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,  left top,  left bottom,  color-stop(0,  #fdfdfd),  color-stop(1,  #eee));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fdfdfd,  #eee);
background: linear-gradient(top,  #fdfdfd,  #eee);
text-align:center;
 }

.trilink_item {
float: left; 
width: 32%;
margin-left:5px;
}

.trilink_right {
float: right; 
width: 32%;
margin-right:5px;
}

.trilink_center {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="trilink_container">

<div class="trilink_item trilink_all">Left Test</div>
<div class="trilink_right trilink_all">Right Text</div>
<div class="trilink_center trilink_all">Centre Text</div>

</div>
```

I've also added the code to **[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVmhP/)**.

BTW, I realise my coding is a bit messy and intend to tidy it up once I have a solution :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` (or `auto`; anything but `visible`) to the `.trilink_center` and you will get what you want I believe ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVmhP/1/)).

This establishes a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) which changes how the flow works. See [this article](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/) for some discussion.

Comment: Thanks, that does work and I will mark as correct answer as you were first :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove double border then just remove `margin` from `left` and `right` divs

```
.trilink_item {
    float: left; 
    width: 32%;
    //margin-left:5px; remove it
    }

.trilink_right {
    float: right; 
    width: 32%;
    //margin-right:5px; remove it
    }
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UVmhP/3/)

Answer (score 0):

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVmhP/6/) if you want to eliminate the double border near the edges. It removes `border-left` and `border-right` for left and right divs respectively

Answer (score 0):

`.trilink_center {

```
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 /* float left or right
 float: left;
```

}`

and that's all