# Div doesn't align to center with margin:auto

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I'm trying to center a div between two others following the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172738/centering-a-div-between-one-thats-floated-right-and-one-thats-floated-left). However, it doesn't work and, inspecting my page's elements, I found out the center div's padding is taking up the whole screen's width, as if it were containing the two other divs. I solved that by setting display:inline-block. The padding now is correct, but the div is still not centered. Did I forget something? Is the inline-block option incorrect, since it wasn't present in the answer to which I linked? Code follows.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu" id="left-menu">
<div class="menu" id="right-menu">
<div class="main-col">
    <canvas id="my-canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
/div>
```

CSS:

```
#left-menu
{
float:left;
margin-right:15px; /*won't be needed if the center div is well positioned*/
}
#right-menu
{
float:right;
margin-left:15px; /*won't be needed if the center div is well positioned*/
}
#main-col
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `display:inline-block` to `display:block` or add `text-align:center` to the `#main-col` container.

Comment: Just adding display:block didn't solve it, but the the text-align option solved the problem, and now I can see why. Thank you.