# How do I make a navigation bar in bootstrap that inline displays nav items left, center and right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation

See the HTML code for the navigation bar below.

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top center">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a><li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a><li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a><li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">item 4</a><li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="brand">
                    <li><p>logo text</p></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="budget">
                    <li><p>item on right</p></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</header>
```

I used the following CSS to center the brand logo. This works fine.

```
.navbar .brand {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100px;
float: none;
list-style: none;}

.center .navbar-inner {
text-align:center;}
```

I got stuck on how to make the item on the right (with the class "budget") move towards the right. I already tried using the navbar-right bootstrap class but this didn't work. I also tried to adjust the CSS I used to center the logo but somehow the item I want to align right 
keeps showing up centered and below the navigation bar. Somebody can tell me how I can display this item inline on the right?

Thanks in advance,

Stijn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your navbar html markup is a bit messy, I decided to make a clean one for your purpose.

Basically I just added one CSS class and got rid of yours.

```
.nav.nav-center {
    margin:0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
}
```

And here your adapted HTML

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>      
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-center brand">
        <li><p>logo text</p></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right budget">
        <li><p>item on right</p></li>

      </ul>      
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to have items on the left as well, you have to change the HTML markup and put the brand element as last between the two floats, like this:

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>      
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li><p>Left Content1</p></li>
        <li><p>Left Content1</p></li>
      </ul>      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right budget">
        <li><p>item on right</p></li>
      </ul>            
      <div class="nav-center brand">logo text</div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header>
```

And change the CSS class to this:

```
.nav-center {
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: 47%;    
}
```

After you finished entering your content, play with the `margin-left` percentage until it fits.

Also read this question for further information on your issue: [centering a div between one that's floated right and one that's floated left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172738/centering-a-div-between-one-thats-floated-right-and-one-thats-floated-left)

[Working example](http://www.bootply.com/J8I1eKLmgX)

Comment: Thanks but when I use this code and start adding items to the left the brand logo moves along with it. I am looking for a solution that keeps the logo in the middle.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed response! Your updated code solved the issue.